# What were the geometric coordinates of the Chicxulub impactor 66 million years ago?

Tags: plate-tectonics, earth-history

At the moment around mexico we can find the leftovers of the Chicxulub impactor which could have extincted most dinosaurs. But 66 million years ago was after the breakdown of Gondwana. So back to those days where did exactly (probably approximately) hit the meteorite. Was it far from Yucatan?

Comment: the chixulub crater was created about 3 times closer to 2020 than to the breakdown of gondwana so i think you might want to modify your question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gondwana

Comment: [Plate Tectonics, 540Ma - Modern World - Scotese Animation 022116b](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_iEWvtKcuQ) at about 5:25 .

Answer (score 1):

Sixty six million years ago the Chicxulub meteorite struck the Yucatan peninsular in the same place as the crater is today. The peninsular hasn't moved very far since then, though some of the continents have, India for example. South America was already well adrift from Africa. At the time, most of Yucatan was probably under a shallow sea, too shallow to slow the impact to any great extent. Struck at that speed (about 55 km per sec), water is as solid as stone, but 50 feet of stone would have done little to slow the speed of such a large bolide. The water and much of the rock beneath it was vaporised.